# ASP.NET MVC3 formatting DateTime

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Hi I'm new to MVC3 and if run into a little problem I can't seem so solve.

I have a value in one of my table's that represents the national holiday of a country. So it only contains a day and a month. Now I'm unable to find a way to set my entities validations this way it only accepts a day/month combination.

I tried using

```
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/mm}")]
```

But then it would only show the days correctly and alwayse make the months "00"

Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: keyword "DateTime MVC3 ASP format". mm means minutes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mm` means *minutes* in a [`DateTime` format string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx). Use `MM` instead for months.